# getLong error using preference

Tags: android, long-integer

i use

```
long lvalue = Long.parseLong(string);
prefEditor.putLong(m_strfileName, lvalue);
prefEditor.commit();
```

Then i do

```
SharedPreferences oSettings = getSharedPreferences("FONECLAY", 0);
long strValue =  (long) oSettings.getLong(string, 0l);
```

Here im getting error E/AndroidRuntime(20770): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to store value into sharedpreferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putLong("Value", mLongValue);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Use below code for retrive long value from sharedpreferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
long mVal = myPrefs.getLong("Value", 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapper class to store long value

```
long lvalue = Long.parseLong(string);
prefEditor.putLong(m_strfileName, new Long(lvalue));
prefEditor.commit();
```